# compass watch ERROR

Tags: ruby, sass, rubygems, compass

I am trying to use Sass with Compass on my static HTML project. This is what I did:

```
$ gem install compass
$ cd <myproject>
$ compass install compass
```

it created following:

```
directory ./sass/
directory ./stylesheets/
   create ./sass/screen.scss 
   create ./sass/print.scss 
   create ./sass/ie.scss 
   create ./stylesheets/screen.css 
   create ./stylesheets/ie.css 
   create ./stylesheets/print.css
```

Then, I start watching scss `compass watch sass:stylesheets`, I get an error:

```
error sass:stylesheets (/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:484:in `read': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /home/pc/test/webproj/sass:stylesheets)
```

Please help!!

Comment: If you're starting a new project I'd drop compass entirely; it's no longer maintained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skimming through the reference it seems that `watch` command is expecting a path to directory. So, your command should be:

```
compass watch sass/stylesheets
```